# How to retrieve the most repeated value in a column present in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I am trying to retrieve the most repeated value in a particular column present in a data frame.Here is my sample data and code below.A

```
data("Forbes2000", package = "HSAUR")
head(Forbes2000)


  rank                name        country             category  sales profits  assets marketvalue
1    1           Citigroup  United States              Banking  94.71   17.85 1264.03      255.30
2    2    General Electric  United States        Conglomerates 134.19   15.59  626.93      328.54
3    3 American Intl Group  United States            Insurance  76.66    6.46  647.66      194.87
4    4          ExxonMobil  United States Oil & gas operations 222.88   20.96  166.99      277.02
5    5                  BP United Kingdom Oil & gas operations 232.57   10.27  177.57      173.54
6    6     Bank of America  United States              Banking  49.01   10.81  736.45      117.55
```

As per my sample data I need to return the most repeated category which is Insurance.

```
subset(subset(Forbes2000,country=="Bermuda")
```

Comment: How about `sort(table(yourdata$category), decreasing=TRUE)[1]`.  There are lots of other ways too!

Comment: I need to return the most repeated value from my data...

Comment: I thought I'd leave that to the reader as an exercise.  `names(sort(table(yourdata$category), decreasing=TRUE)[1])`. But Josh makes a good point below, what if you've got a tie!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
tail(names(sort(table(Forbes2000$category))), 1)
```

Answer (score 13):

In case two or more categories may be tied for most frequent, use something like this:

```
x <- c("Insurance", "Insurance", "Capital Goods", "Food markets", "Food markets")
tt <- table(x)
names(tt[tt==max(tt)])
[1] "Food markets" "Insurance"
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way with the data.table package, which is faster for large data sets:

```
set.seed(1)
x=sample(seq(1,100), 5000000, replace = TRUE)
```

**method 1 (solution proposed above)**

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
tt <- table(x)
names(tt[tt==max(tt)])
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Time difference of 4.883488 secs

**method 2 (DATA TABLE)**

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
ds <- data.table( x )
setkey(ds, x)
sorted <- ds[,.N,by=list(x)]

most_repeated_value <- sorted[order(-N)]$x[1]
most_repeated_value

end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

Time difference of 0.328033 secs

Comment: tucson, nice. I think `as.data.table(ds)[, .N, by=x][, x[N == max(N)]]` also does the job, which takes 0.06s on my laptop. As a FYI, no need to `setkey` for aggregations.

Comment: @Arun Thank you. Your solution should be on top of this page.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is coming a little late, but I built the following function that does the job in less than a second for my dataframe that contains more than 50,000 rows:

```
print_count_of_unique_values <- function(df, column_name, remove_items_with_freq_equal_or_lower_than = 0, return_df = F, 
                                         sort_desc = T, return_most_frequent_value = F)
{
  temp <- df[column_name]
  output <- as.data.frame(table(temp))
  names(output) <- c("Item","Frequency")
  output_df <- output[  output[[2]] > remove_items_with_freq_equal_or_lower_than,  ]

  if (sort_desc){
    output_df <- output_df[order(output_df[[2]], decreasing = T), ]
  }

  cat("\nThis is the (head) count of the unique values in dataframe column '", column_name,"':\n")
  print(head(output_df))

  if (return_df){
    return(output_df)
  }

  if (return_most_frequent_value){
      output_df$Item <- as.character(output_df$Item)
      output_df$Frequency <- as.numeric(output_df$Frequency)
      most_freq_item <- output_df[1, "Item"]
      cat("\nReturning most frequent item: ", most_freq_item)
      return(most_freq_item)
  }
}
```

so if you have a dataframe called "df" and a column called "name" and you want to know the most comment value in the "name" column, you could run:

```
most_common_name <- print_count_of_unique_values(df=df, column_name = "name", return_most_frequent_value = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a function:

```
get_mode <- function(x){
  return(names(sort(table(x), decreasing = T, na.last = T)[1]))
}
```

and then do

```
get_mode(Forbes3000$category)
```

The reason I created a function is that I have to this kind of thing very often.

Comment: I like this solution, makes it easy to apply across a data frame and calculate this quickly for all values.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the easiest (for me) to read and to remember:

```
names(which.max(table(Forbes2000$category)))
```

Extra notes on efficiency: This approach avoids sorting the table entries (finding the max is cheaper than a full sort). The most efficient solution would avoid a full tabulation. You can imagine an Rcpp solution that loops through the source vector and keeps a running tabulation but stops before the end, when the contest is already over. If anyone writes that solution, ping me so I can give you a +1 and edit this answer to reference your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the function option from @Malvika makes it easy to apply across a table and get these values for every column

```
#create a mode function
get_mode_name <- function(x){
  return(names(sort(table(x), decreasing = T, na.last = T)[1]))
}

get_mode_value <- function(x){
  return(unname(sort(table(x), decreasing = T, na.last = T)[1]))
}

get_mode_pct<- function(x){
  return(unname(sort(table(x), decreasing = T, na.last = T)[1])/length(x))
}

#Identify character columns
type_table <- sapply(table_name, class)

#create vector numeric and character types
num_table <- (unname(type_table) == "numeric")
char_table <- (unname(type_table) == "character")

#View the modes of character columns
mode_name <- apply(table_name[,char_table], 2, function(x) get_mode_name(x))    
mode_value <- apply(table_name[,char_table], 2, function(x) get_mode_value(x))
mode_pct <- apply(table_name[,char_table], 2, function(x) get_mode_pct(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table(Forbes2000$CategoryName, useNA="ifany")`. This will give you the list of all possible values in the chosen category and the number of times each value was used in that particular data frame.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `Rfast::Table`.

```
Rfast::Table(as.character(Forbes2000$CategoryName))
```

the you can get the maximum value.