# Retrieve the most repeated (x, y) values in two columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am storing `(x, y)` values in a dataframe. I want to return the most frequently appearing `(x, y)` combination.

Here is an example:

```
> x = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
> y = c(1, 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12)
> xy = data.frame(x, y)
> xy
  x  y
1 1  1
2 1  1
3 2  5
4 3  6
5 4  9
6 5 10
7 6 12
```

The most common `(x, y)` value would be `(1, 1)`.

I tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187187/how-to-retrieve-the-most-repeated-value-in-a-column-present-in-a-data-frame) for a single column. It works for a single column, but does not work for an aggregate of two columns.

```
> tail(names(sort(table(xy$x))), 1)
[1] "1"
> tail(names(sort(table(xy$x, xy$y))), 1)
NULL
```

How do I retrieve the most repeated (x, y) values in two columns in a data frame in R?

EDIT: `c(1, 2)` should be considered distinct from `c(2, 1)`.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570149/find-most-frequent-combination-of-values-in-a-data-frame - though there is a wider set of answers to this post already.

Comment: The question is not clear. What happens if a line contains `c(1,2)` and another `c(2,1)` ? Are these two lines pointing to the same couple?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel `c(1, 2)` should be considered distinct from `c(2, 1)`.

Comment: `table(apply(xy, 1, toString))`

Comment: @Khashaa I think `table(do.call(paste, xy))` is better, but I already posted it...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Despite all the plus votes, a hybrid of @DavidArenburg and my approaches

```
res = do.call("paste", c(xy, sep="\r"))
which.max(tabulate(match(res, res)))
```

might be simple and effective.)

Maybe it seems a little round-about, but a first step is to transform the possibly arbitrary values in the columns of `xy` to integers ranging from 1 to the number of unique values in the column

```
x = match(xy[[1]], unique(xy[[1]]))
y = match(xy[[2]], unique(xy[[2]]))
```

Then encode the combination of columns to unique values

```
v = x + (max(x) - 1L) * y
```

Indexing minimizes the range of values under consideration, and encoding reduces a two-dimensional problem to a single dimension. These steps reduce the space required of any tabulation (as with `table()` in other answers) to the minimum, without creating character vectors.

If one wanted to most common occurrence in a single dimension, then one could index and tabulate `v`

```
tbl = tabulate(match(v, v))
```

and find the index of the first occurrence of the maximum value(s), e.g.,

```
df[which.max(tbl),]
```

Here's a function to do the magic

```
whichpairmax <- function(x, y) {
    x = match(x, unique(x)); y = match(y, unique(y))
    v = x + (max(x) - 1L) * y
    which.max(tabulate(match(v, v)))
}
```

and a couple of tests

```
> set.seed(123)
> xy[whichpairmax(xy[[1]], xy[[2]]),]
  x y
1 1 1
> xy1 = xy[sample(nrow(xy)),]
> xy1[whichpairmax(xy1[[1]], xy1[[2]]),]
  x y
1 1 1
> xy1
  x  y
3 2  5
5 4  9
7 6 12
4 3  6
6 5 10
1 1  1
2 1  1
```

For an arbitrary data.frame

```
whichdfmax <- function(df) {
    v = integer(nrow(df))
    for (col in df) {
        col = match(col, unique(col))
        v = col + (max(col) - 1L) * match(v, unique(v))
    }
    which.max(tabulate(match(v, v)))
}
```

Comment: I wonder how that would work if one would like to do this for lets say 10 columns at once.

Comment: @DavidArenburg actually I'd be tempted to take your route (I think also by `duplicated.data.frame()`) of pasting the columns together then `tabulate(match(res, res))`, otherwise perhaps creating v by iterating over columns.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure how will the desired output should look like, but here's a possible solution

```
res <- table(do.call(paste, xy))
res[which.max(res)]
# 1 1 
#   2
```

In order to get the actual values, one could do

```
res <- do.call(paste, xy) 
xy[which.max(ave(seq(res), res, FUN = length)), ]
#   x y
# 1 1 1
```

Comment: Would you also add to your answer how to retrieve each component of `res[which.max(res)]`? Such as how to get the `x` value and the `y` value.

Comment: Actually, disregard that edit. I did a mistake. Let me think it thru.

Comment: Thanks! `df = xy[which.max(res), ]` stores a data frame in `df`. The `x` and `y` values can be accessed by  `df$x` and `df$y`.

Comment: It's not quiite that simple, because `res` is <= `xy`

Comment: Oh, I see now. I'll withdraw the check mark for now.

Comment: Ok, I've made an edit, but my guess that Matrins answer will be the best one (as always).

Comment: Okay, I've accepted Martin's answer since it is very, very good (though your answer is very good too). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(xy)[, .N,list(x,y)][which.max(N)]
#   x y N
#1: 1 1 2
```

Comment: Looks like you won the speed test.

Answer (score 4):

```
t<-table(xy)
which(t == max(t), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

**Update:**

As pointed out by David Arenburg, the initial code returned just the index of the values from the `table(xy)` function. If you need the values and maybe the number of occurrences of the max couple you can try this:

```
t<-table(xy)
indexes <- which(t == max(t), arr.ind = TRUE)[1,]
x_value <- dimnames(t)$x[indexes["x"]]
y_value <- dimnames(t)$y[indexes["y"]]
rep_number <- max(t)
```

Now I suspect there is better way to write the last three lines of code, but I'm still new to the R world

Comment: I think this will give wrong results for lets say `x = c(1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5) ;y = c(1, 1, 5, 10, 9, 2, 10) ;xy = data.frame(x, y)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg It is giving the index `4, 5` of `t`.  You are right that the results are not the expected as per the OP's post, but the index is correct, right?

Comment: @akrun I don't have time to validate right now, but I trust your judgment :)

Comment: indexes are related to the table(xy), they should be correct

Comment: Perhaps `data.frame(x=rownames(t)[row(t)], y=colnames(t)[col(t)])[t==max(t),]`

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
x = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
y = c(1, 1, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12)
xy = data.frame(x, y)

table(xy)
y
x   1 5 6 9 10 12
1 2 0 0 0  0  0
2 0 1 0 0  0  0
3 0 0 1 0  0  0
4 0 0 0 1  0  0
5 0 0 0 0  1  0
6 0 0 0 0  0  1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(xy)
tail(DT[, Count := .N, by = c("x", "y")][ order(Count) ], 1)
    x y Count
 1: 1 1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
xy %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  top_n(1)
```

Comment: Also needed:  `library(magrittr)`

Comment: Loading dplyr should be sufficient for this example; does this not run for you as is? "dplyr only exports %>% from magrittr, but magrittr contains many other useful functions. To use them, load magrittr explicitly with library(magrittr)." http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/05/21/dplyr-0-2/

Comment: To be honest, I didn't try it.  I was unaware that `dplyr` exports the pipe function.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

xy %>% group_by(x, y) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
   ungroup %>% filter(n==max(n)) %>% select(-n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but here's a time test:

```
x<-sample(1:10,1e5,rep=TRUE)
y<-sample(1:10,1e5,rep=TRUE)


martin  <- function(x, y) {
    x = match(x, unique(x)); y = match(y, unique(y))
    v = x + (max(x) - 1L) * y
    which.max(tabulate(match(v, v)))
}
akrun <-function(x,y) {
    library(data.table)
    xy<-data.frame(x,y)
setDT(xy)[, .N,list(x,y)][which.max(N)]
}
mucio <-function(x,y){
    xy<-data.frame(x,y)
    t<-table(xy)
indexes <- which(t == max(t), arr.ind = TRUE)[1,]
x_value <- dimnames(t)$x[indexes["x"]]
y_value <- dimnames(t)$y[indexes["y"]]
rep_number <- max(t)

}

sam<-function(x,y){
    library(dplyr)
    xy<-data.frame(x,y)
xy %>%
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup %>%
  top_n(1)

}
dimitris<-function(x,y){
    library(dplyr)
xy<-data.frame(x,y)
xy %>% group_by(x, y) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>% 
   ungroup %>% filter(n==max(n)) %>% select(-n)

}

microbenchmark(martin(x,y),akrun(x,y),mucio(x,y),sam(x,y),dimitris(x,y),times=5)

Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq       mean    median         uq
   martin(x, y) 11.727217 14.246913  41.359218 14.384385  82.639796
    akrun(x, y)  4.426462  4.613420   4.866548  4.892432   5.011406
    mucio(x, y) 73.938586 74.037568 103.941459 79.516207 145.232870
      sam(x, y)  8.356426  8.586212   8.919787  8.586521   8.775792
 dimitris(x, y)  8.618394  8.738228   9.252105  9.063965   9.075298
        max neval cld
  83.797780     5  a 
   5.389018     5  a 
 146.982062     5   b
  10.293983     5  a 
  10.764640     5  a
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)    
sqldf('SELECT x, y 
          FROM xy 
          GROUP BY (x||y) 
          ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
          LIMIT 1')
  x y
1 1 1
```

If we'd like to show a frequency column, and not just one row (in case there are any ties):

```
x = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 12)
y = c(1, 1, 5, 6, 9, 12, 12)
xy = data.frame(x, y)

sqldf('SELECT x, y, COUNT(*) AS freq
      FROM xy 
      GROUP BY (x||y) 
      ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC')

   x  y freq
1  1  1    2
2 12 12    2
3  2  5    1
4  3  6    1
5  4  9    1
```